# Unable to set values to local Storage

Tags: javascript

My code is like this

```
var searchPreferences = new function() {
    this.setValues = localStorage.setItem('searchPreferenceData', JSON.stringify({
        clientName: document.getElementById('clientName').value,
        carrier: document.getElementById('carrierName').value,
        status: document.getElementById('ShipmentStatus').value,
        genericView: document.getElementById('ddl_view').value


    }));
    this.getData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('searchPreferenceData'));
    this.showValues = new function() {
        document.getElementById('clientName').value = GetData.clientName;

    }
}
```

And I a calling this function like this

```
searchPreferences.setValues();
```

inside a button  click. But no value is added to local storage. Can any one point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: new function () ?, should be just "function()"

Comment: @Hacketo I think he's instantiating while assigning, Not a good practice. It will threw errors if in restrict mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setValues` is not a function. It is set to the result of the call to `setItem` which will be undefined.

You probably have an error like this in your console:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Wrap it in a function:

```
this.setValues = function() {
    localStorage.setItem('searchPreferenceData', JSON.stringify({
        clientName: document.getElementById('clientName').value,
        carrier: document.getElementById('carrierName').value,
        status: document.getElementById('ShipmentStatus').value,
        genericView: document.getElementById('ddl_view').value


    })
};
```

Comment: changed the code as you wrote. now getting an error "uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( " at line  setValues:  function() {

Comment: Oops, sorry you have it defined in a function, not an object :) Check updated code

Comment: now new error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setValues' of undefined " at line searchPreferences.setValues();

Answer (score 3):

*I'd like to edit my answer to explain more:*
the code seems like implementation of Singleton design pattern, but in a wrong manner.

have it in mind that instantiating a function while assigning at the same statement of code, is not a good idea. when you instantiate a function the type of members become "data" not "function":

```
typeof searchPreferences.getData == "object"
```

I mean a statement like

```
var fuc = new function () {}
```

executes the function and the returned result is assigned to `func`.

 what do you think we get if we call `searchPreferences.getData` immediately after defining `searchPreferences` like you did?
you expect it to return null because you've not set anything to localstorage yet, but it returns an object with values of inputs.

the correct way is to define a funjction and instantiate it when you need, or in the best approach, just define a function and call it when you need:

```
var searchPreferences = function() {}
```

Answer (score 3):

you've instantiated the function. you need to call it like a member of object not a function

Answer (score 3):

the problem is that you are using `new` keyword to instantiate the function before you need to use it. the result becomes an object and the stored in `searchPreferences`. it's not a function to get called

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var searchPreferences = new function() {

     this.setValues =function(){ 
  try{
alert("i m in");
 localStorage.setItem('searchPreferenceData', JSON.stringify({
        clientName: document.getElementById('clientName').value,
        carrier: document.getElementById('carrierName').value,
        status: document.getElementById('ShipmentStatus').value,
        genericView: document.getElementById('ddl_view').value  
  }));
}catch(err){alert(err.message);}
}

    this.getData =function(){ 
 return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('searchPreferenceData'));

}
     this.showValues =   function() {
    try{
        document.getElementById('clientName').value = this.getData().clientName;
   }catch(err){alert(err.message)}   

}




}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="clientName" />
<input type="text" id="carrierName" />
<input type="text" id="ShipmentStatus" />
<input type="text" id="ddl_view" />
<button  onclick="searchPreferences.setValues()">Store data</button>
<button  onclick="searchPreferences.showValues()">Get data</button>



</body>
</html>
```